# BASH: SSH into server, query MYSQL Funny stuff

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, heredoc, command-substitution

I am having some trouble with a script of mine that is supposed to SSHs into my server, run a mysql query, and return a specific value.

My problem is that I am getting an Access Denied error when I use command substitution [ $() and `` ] - but without command substitution I don't get the result saved to a variable.

I have full privileges, and the password is correct.

```
  ssh root@SERVER.com  << EOFMARK
    example=$(mysql -h localhost -u root -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD myDatabase -e "SELECT now();")  
    echo "Variable is $example"
  EOFMARK

echo "My goal is to read the variable here: $example"
```

Comment: Please check if you are using password that has privileges on localhost..you can check by show grants for root@'localhost' and your password in script should be same as password by this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to

- immediately execute the command and
- give it the query it is supposed to execute.

This way:

```
example=$(ssh root@SERVER.com mysql -h localhost -u root -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" myDatabase -e '"SELECT now();"')
echo "My goal is to read the variable here: $example"
```

would be the way to go.

If you really need it at *both* places, you either might want to have a script on the server, or you could try

```
example=$(ssh root@SERVER.com 'example=$(mysql -h localhost -u root -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" myDatabase -e "SELECT now();"); echo "Variable is $example")
echo "My goal is to read the variable here: $example"
```

In order to stick on the heredoc, you could as well try

```
example=$(ssh root@SERVER.com  << EOFMARK
    example=$(mysql -h localhost -u root -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD myDatabase -e "SELECT now();")  
    echo "Variable is $example"
EOFMARK)

echo "My goal is to read the variable here: $example"
```

in order to have the variable on the client side as well.

---

Due to whatever, I can't get my head around the heredoc example.

But the others should look like

```
example=$(ssh root@SERVER.com 'mysql -NB -h localhost -u root -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" myDatabase -e "SELECT now();"')
echo "My goal is to read the variable here: $example"
```

which gives exactly the output into the local variable, or

```
example=$(ssh root@SERVER.com 'example=$(mysql -NB -h localhost -u root -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD" myDatabase -e "SELECT now();"); echo "Variable is $example")
echo "My goal is to read the variable here: $example"
```

but you should be aware that here, the local output looks like (e. g.)

```
My goal is to read the variable here: Variable is 2014-03-07 20:42:23
```

as the sub string `Variable is` gets output as well.

Comment: I am adapting my script to this answer but it apparently has a few rough edges. For a bash noob I'm pretty stuck in escaping everything. Could you address this issue?

Comment: @JHAWN Which of the 3?

Comment: The last one would be the best, though all three work. (Ignoring the escaping issues)

Answer (score 1):

You should **escape** the substitutions that has to be done at remote host:

Try:

```
 ssh root@SERVER.com  << EOFMARK
    example=\$(mysql -h localhost -u root -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD myDatabase -e "SELECT now();")  
    echo "Variable is \$example"
  EOFMARK
```

You can follow @glglgl advise, and capture standard output of your ssh command into a local variable. But I would use a local mysql client and I would grant privileges to access database. If you have a firewall that prevents you from remote accesing 3306, I would ssh forward port.

```
example=$(mysql -h SERVER.com -u root -p myDatabase -e "SELECT now();")
```

That's the right approach. No ssh, and interactive password, no accesible via `ps -ef| grep mysql`

Comment: This works perfectly from within the scope of the SSH heredoc, however I need access to the variable from outside of the heredoc as well. Could you advise?